# substitute a certain substring with other variables

Tags: android, string

Hello I have a question about substring replacement. I have many 
different string in hexadecimal like: (string have most different length)

`String str =  2D 10 02 B3 B2 B1 AF AE AD AC AB A9 89 A9 88 A7 A5 A4 A2 A1 00 00;`

I want to replace "A989" to "A8" and "A988" to "A8" (can be on different positions)

but it doesn't work :/. my code so far:

```
if(str.indexOf("A9")!=0)
 {
     if(str.indexOf("A988")!=0)
       {
        str_help = str.replace("A988","A8");
       }
      if(str.indexOf("A989")!=0)
       {
        str_help= str.replace("A989","A9");
       }
 }
 else{
     str_help= str;
 }
```

hope you understand and can help me :)

Comment: You don't need to check if `indexOf != 0` because in the str.replace(strOld,strNew) if the str does not contain strOld, it wont change anything. Just for clarity in your code

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work fine:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str = "2D1002B3B2B1AFAEADACABA989A988A7A5A4A2A10000";
    String str_help = str.replace("A988","A8");
    str_help= str_help.replace("A989","A9");

    System.out.println(str_help);
  }
```